# How to find the distribution in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, statistics, distribution

I have data set from Goodreads with Number of books read over a year with details like number of pages of the each book, date read etc. I want to know in which month/week I have read most/least. How do I do that in Python ?

Comment: you should probably use groupby, check the docs. it should look something like:  data.groupby(['year','month']).min()

Comment: Could you post sample of dataframe? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve